# Resolve state using external module service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a factory in module1:

```
angular.module('module1',[]);
angular.module('module1').factory('factory1', function($resource, $q){
  return 'prmose response';//This will include promise
});
```

I want to call this factory in resolve of a state created in module2:

```
angular.module('module2',['module1']);
angular.module('module2').config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('stateName',{
    url: '/url',
    templateUrl: '/url/path.html',
    controller: 'controllerName',
    reolve:{
      data: function(factory1){
        return factory1;
      }
    }

  })
}])
```

When I am using a service from module2, then it works but its not working when using any service from another module.

Kindly hrlp me to solve this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

when you have two modules you can depend module `A` on module `B` in their decleration.

That exposes all the services, directives, factories etc from each.

you simply do

```
angular.module('A', ['b'])
```

What this means is you are creating a module called `A`. The array after is a list of dependencies that your module `A` requires. So long as all those dependencies have been included on the page (i believe before your module `A`) then it will all work and allow you to inject things from each.

```
//pseudo example
angular.module('B', [])
.service('myService', function () {
    this.hey = function () {
        console.log('You guys!');
    }
});
angular.module('A', ['B'])
.controller('test', function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.hey()' //You guys!
});
```

This list some useful information on the subject: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Yes, I already done the same. Still its not working.                                                            And its working perfectly when I am using that service as a dependancy in controller, but not working when using in resolve of state.

Comment: But your trying to resolve the state of `module1` which is a dependency, not the application being run if that makes sense. Surely it should be `module2` that your resolve the state in?

Comment: Yes its module2, but when I am trying to resolve using any service as a dependency from same module then it works and if I used any service from any other module then it does not work. And when I am using the same in controller it works. The problem I am facing is only while resolve in state.